Storybook showing error while listing the components of ParkUI
When I tried to run pnpm run storybook
It showing the error below:
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRootProps')
  at renderWithHooks (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:11548:26))
  at updateForwardRef (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:14325:28))
  at beginWork (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:15946:22))
  at beginWork$1 (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:19753:22))
  at performUnitOfWork (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:19201:20))
  at workLoopSync (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:19137:13))
  at renderRootSync (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:19116:15))
  at recoverFromConcurrentError (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:18736:28))
  at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (/node_modules/.cache/storybook/1c3385a5d25e538d10b518b310c74d3ca2690b6aaffeadccd74da79736171f86/sb-vite/deps/chunk-J7SVWHEE.js?v=0c2c1e66:18684:30))

Preview.ts
import "../src/index.css";
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

Main.ts
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {},
  },
};
export default config;


is there any additional configuration is needed ?
I have tried to reconfigure pandacss and parkui again but issue still exists!
